# Image displays bigger in webbrowser than its original size

Tags: image, browser

I'm having issues adding an image to a website. The original PNG image is 200px wide, but when I display it in the website, the image becomes bigger. Even when I open the image on another tab (so no HTML) it still is bigger and therefore blurred. So it can't be any HTML or CSS setting. When I download the image from the website and open it with an image viewer, the size is ok again. On itself it wouldn't be much of an issue, but the original picture is really sharp and the end result looks blurred.

[image: Example]

Using the developer tools, hovering over the image the boundaries are drawn, and it indicates that the image is indeed 200px. The issue occurs consistently on Firefox, Chromium and Chrome. That would mean that it is not browser related. The image settings in the browser are scaled at 100%. The conclusion could be that it is system related (Ubuntu 18.04 I think), but to my knowledge there is no setting for browser-related zoom adjustments. System settings would also impact the original picture.

The image looks even blurred when looking at the website from my mobile phone, so maybe not even system-related. The picture is added to the website of https://www.wheellist.info. Anyone out there with a clue on what is happening or how to correct this?